# Creating JDBC Connection Pool in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hikaricp

I am newbie with java and i need help with how to create connection pool for JDBC in my java application project. 
I have been able to connect to my database but the performance of my application is slow since i call on the connection on every frame as i saw on a lots of video tutorials on youtube.

This is how i connect to the database. I call on the connection in every frame like `DBConnection.getConnectDB()` in most of my frame.

How can i create a JDBC connection pool for java in netbeans.  Thank you

**DBConnect**

```
public class DBConnection {


    public static Connection ConnectDB(){

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server/db_name","user","pass");
            System.out.println("Connected");
            return conn;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            return null;
       }}     
}
```

**update**

```
public static Connection ConnectDB(){


 HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
```

config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simpsons");

```
config.setUsername("username");
config.setPassword("pass");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    return (Connection) new HikariDataSource(config);

    }

}
```

**Console**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Access denied for user 'qweqsbra_wagyingo'@'197.251.142.100' (using password: YES)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:543)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:535)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:111)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at wagyingohostel.DBConnection.DBConnection.ConnectDB(DBConnection.java:41)
    at wagyingohostel.LoginAndRegistration.Login.<init>(Login.java:34)
    at wagyingohostel.LoginAndRegistration.Login$4.run(Login.java:228)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'qweqsbra_wagyingo'@'197.251.142.100' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2198)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2229)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:443)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:514)
    ... 19 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 20 seconds)
```

Comment: Are you using multi-threading for DB access?

Comment: Don't mix UI code with other layers.  This is a very shallow "pool" - there's only one connection in it.  Use one that your betters have written for you (e.g. DBCP).

Comment: @PM77-1, there is multithreading . My application takes long to respond when i try to navigate from one frame to another

Comment: the user has permissions ?  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'qweqsbra_wagyingo'@'197.251.142.100' (using password: YES) , this a autentication problem.

Comment: @IvanFontalvo, yes the user has permission. I am using the same auth credentials i used in my initial database connection ( which works but slows down my application).

Comment: Are you using the correct database? The code you added still shows the "simpsons" database

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven or gradle (you should be) you can use a pool like HikariCP and create a jdbc connection pool like this.

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simpsons");
config.setUsername("bart");
config.setPassword("51mp50n");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Here is a more detailed [example configuring multiple hikaricp pools](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/database-connection-pooling-in-java-with-hikaricp)

Comment: create that in a class file? Do i need import the HikariConfig ? It throws an error

Comment: Yes you need to import the Jar. Directions can be found here using maven / gradle https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP.

Comment: kindly look at my update... i get this error `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

Comment: That should just be a warning not an error. It means you don't have any implementation of SLF4J wired up. That means you won't be able to use logging but it should still work fine.

Comment: I am not able to connect to connect to my database now. Access is denied as well.. Check my update and see console

Answer (score -1):

You need to Configuring JNDI DataSource for Database Connection Pooling in Netbeans.Please follow the the steps mentioned  in below URL to create a connection pool using Netbeans ID

https://dzone.com/articles/nb-class-glassfish-mysql-jdbc